# Generate a new array with count of property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have an array in my state :

```
projects: [
{ title: 'todo 1', person: 'Sam', status: 'ongoing'},
{ title: 'project', person: 'Jack', status: 'complete' },
{ title: 'Design video', person: 'Tim', status: 'complete' },
{ title: 'Create a forum', person: 'Jade', status: 'overdue' },
{ title: 'application', person: 'Jade', status: 'ongoing'},],
```

From this array (projects), I would like to generate a new array with Javascript and to get this result :

```
totalByPersonAndStatus : [
{person : 'Sam', complete: 0, ongoing: 1, overdue: 0 },
{person : 'Jack', complete: 1, ongoing: 0, overdue: 0 },
{person : 'Tim', complete: 1, ongoing: 0, overdue: 0 },
{person : 'Jade', complete: 0, ongoing: 1, overdue: 1 },]
```

I tried it

```
totalProjectsByPersonAndStatus: state => {
state.projects.forEach(name => {
  state. totalByPersonAndStatus["name"] = name.person;
});

return state. totalByPersonAndStatus;
```

The problem, if a make a console.log(this.totalByPersonAndStatus) I have an object with only the data of projects.name `[name: "Jade", __ob__: Observer]`

Can you help me ? 
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide code.

Comment: I think the answer is "yes, you can be helped" along with, "help me, help you by showing what part you are stuck on"

Comment: You added a `name` field to `totalByPersonAndStatus` array, but you did not add `complete`, `ongoing` or `overdue` fields, nor any logic to indicate how their values should be arrived at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce

```js
let projects =[{title:'todo1',person:'Sam',status:'ongoing'},{title:'project',person:'Jack',status:'complete'},{title:'Designvideo',person:'Tim',status:'complete'},{title:'Createaforum',person:'Jade',status:'overdue'},{title:'application',person:'Jade',status:'ongoing'},]

let desired = projects.reduce((output,{person,status}) => {
  if( output[person] ){
    output[person][status]++
  } else {
    output[person] = {
      person,
      complete: Number(status==='complete'),
      ongoing: Number(status==='ongoing'),
      overdue: Number(status==='overdue')
    }
  }
  return output;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(desired))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and destructuring like this:

```js
const projects=[{title:'todo 1',person:'Sam',status:'ongoing'},{title:'project',person:'Jack',status:'complete'},{title:'Design video',person:'Tim',status:'complete'},{title:'Create a forum',person:'Jade',status:'overdue'},{title:'application',person:'Jade',status:'ongoing'}]

const merged = projects.reduce((acc,{person,status})=>{
  acc[person] = acc[person] || { person, ongoing:0, complete:0, overdue:0}
  acc[person][status]++;
  return acc;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

The goal is create an object `merged` with each `person` as key and then increment based on the statuses:

```
{
  "Sam": {
    "person": "Sam",
    "ongoing": 1,
    "complete": 0,
    "overdue": 0
  },
  "Jack": {

  }
  ...
}
```

Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), to get the final array.

You could make it a one-liner:

```js
const projects=[{title:'todo 1',person:'Sam',status:'ongoing'},{title:'project',person:'Jack',status:'complete'},{title:'Design video',person:'Tim',status:'complete'},{title:'Create a forum',person:'Jade',status:'overdue'},{title:'application',person:'Jade',status:'ongoing'}],

output = Object.values(projects.reduce((a,{person,status})=>
  ((a[person] = a[person] || {person,ongoing:0,complete:0,overdue:0})[status]++,a),{}))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Awesome use of de structuring

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Set for people and statuses by iterating through the projects, a set has only unique values so sets are a convenience, iterate through your people set creating a new object with all the statuses initialized to 0, then iterate over the projects to increment the various statuses that apply.  This method allows any number of new statuses to be added without changing the code - dynamic.

```
var people = new Set();
var status = new Set();   

projects.forEach((p)=>{
    people.add(p.person);
    status.add(p.status);
});

var totalByPersonAndStatus = [];

people.forEach((person)=>{
    let peeps = { "person": person };
    status.forEach((stat)=>{
        peeps[stat] = 0;
    });
    projects.forEach((project)=>{
        if (project.person === person) { peeps[project.status]++; }
    });
    totalByPersonAndStatus.push(peeps);
});
```